# HTML 5 and CSS Style Change Upon Screen Size

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, css

Sorry if this post is too many of question, but because i weak in web design but i want to do these effect in my website, could you guy please let me know on how to do it ?

First...Please visit this site
http://net.tutsplus.com/

**Question 1 :** May i know how could i do the effect of resizing in Asp MVC 3 ?
when our site got a sidebar user screen size less than 1280x800, it will display single column of sidebar. When user screen size larger than 1280x800, it will display two column of sidebar.

**Question 2 :** when the screen size is too small, left side of site will display only about 20px of margin. All the image and background will hidden. exact like when you re-size your browser when opening nettuts site.

Comment: Question 2 is a statement, not a question and I'm not sure if it describes what you want to achieve or what you want to stop. Question 3 is unrelated to the other questions, it should be separated out in to its own question.

Comment: sorry XD i mean how to make it like that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to adjust the layout of a page with respect to the size of the viewport that it is being displayed on is with CSS Media queries. Before you do anything, read this:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

It's practically the bible on the subject.

After that, give the specs a read:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

The less CSS framework comes with a set of useful media queries and is something I use as a very simple framework:

http://lessframework.com/

Comment: yea...i think it is less framework !!! LIKE IT =D and saw many sample site does this !!! Just Nice and Thx to all...finally get my answer ^^

Answer (score 2):

It depends of the positioning atribute: absolute, relative or fixed..
Try to use percentage rather than an absolute, relative or fixed value.

Otherwise try to control the left-margin, right-margin, top and bottom and test, test and more test until it get what you expect.

I do this myself all the time, and always work.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to Question 1**
This is not ASP but JavaScript. Basically you will need a script that is launched each time you resize the browser. It should then check the new viewport width and modify some of the CSS for the sidebar

Comment: can you please share me some sample ?